# Can I prevent my application cannot be killed by another application?

Tags: java, android

I have my android application and I suspect that another application when is running, kill all my threads and this it's causing a lot of problem for me.

There some questions:

1- Another application can do that? I mean, when the app is running on screen, that can kill another threads running on background?

2- If this happening, can I make something to prevent that? Or detect if is really happening (killing threads)?

Thanks!

PS: sorry for my bad english

Comment: Do you have anything in the logs? Are you sure it is not _your_ application misbehaving?

Comment: While other apps aren't really supposed to be able to explicitly do that, in practical terms a foreground app consuming enough resources may necessarily result in the system reaping those in the background.

Comment: -stephan -fge my application running normally on background. But, I have the information that competitor are "doing that", and i have to make sure that not really happening

Answer (score 0):

*Rodrigo, since you told me by email that your application wasn't wrapped in a Service. That's the first place you should start.*

- Wrap your code in a [Service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) (this will ensure that if the system gets low on resources, it won't be the first thing that gets killed)
- But do still use another thread(s) from inside your Service (so that your main thread doesn't get blocked).
- Declare to the system that your Service is in the foreground (even it's in the background).

> A foreground service is a service that's considered to be something
>   the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for the system
>   to kill when low on memory. A foreground service must provide a
>   notification for the status bar, which is placed under the "Ongoing"
>   heading, which means that the notification cannot be dismissed unless
>   the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.
>
> For example, a music player that plays music from a service should be
>   set to run in the foreground, because the user is explicitly aware of
>   its operation. The notification in the status bar might indicate the
>   current song and allow the user to launch an activity to interact with
>   the music player.

- Place as much of the functionality in the cloud as you can. For instance, instead of your application polling a web server every 10 seconds for an incoming customer request. Have GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) ping the phone, or have the web site send your app an SMS, telling it to fetch the new request from the server. Since your app will be using a Broadcast Receiver, then it won't need to be running in the background as much.
- Learn to use Alarm Manager. This will relaunch your Service if for some reason it gets killed.
- Avoid sending gps updates as much as possible, when the car isn't moving, or when the driver is on a break, on lunch, or only send updates when the phone is plugged into the car charger. Etc. There are some frameworks out there that are designed to minimize the use of the gps antenna and the data plan. Make use of those as much as possible.
- And if the data connection isn't reliable. Avoid using the gps antenna until you get to a place with a better connection. Using gps takes a lot of power. It can even make your phone really hot. Whatever you do, avoid powering the gps antenna as much as you can. Technically, you could even send sms to update the server on the coordinates of the car (assuming the customer has an unlimited sms/texting plan).